# Is an unordered_set modified internally?

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I've been reading the [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/)  site and trying to make sure that my *unordered_set* of numbers won't be modified in any way.  The site says that the elements of a container are not sorted which is the case with plain *set*.

The site also says this:

> Internally, the elements in the `unordered_set` are not sorted in any
>   particular order, but organized into buckets depending on their hash
>   values to allow for fast access to individual elements directly by
>   their values.

I have no clue what that means really (can you explain btw.?). Consider following example:

```
typedef const std::unordered_set<short> set_t;
set_t some_set = {1,3,5,7,9,12,14,16,18,19,21,23,25,27,30,32,34,36};
```

Can I make sure that the above set "some_set" will never be changed and that the numbers will always stay in the same order (because this is the goal here)?
I'm also not planning to insert or remove numbers from the set.

Comment: It is implemented as a [Hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) (exactly which variant I do not know but it *is* modified internally when an item is added or removed, else the state would not be able to change)

Comment: You can't rely on any order.

Comment: The `unordered` containers store the data in a "random" order, but they're _really_ fast.  If the order matters, `set` will sort them, or `vector` which doesn't rearrange them at all.

Comment: @MooingDuck Well set will order ascending, not the order they are inserted, just to keep it clear for OP..

Comment: thank you for your valuable comments, i see now.

Comment: Maybe they should've called it `disordered_set`.

Comment: Hoping for maintained order in a container that, by its very name, claims to have none, seems a bit of a stretch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef const std::unordered_set<short> set_t;
set_t some_set = {1,3,5,7,9,12,14,16,18,19,21,23,25,27,30,32,34,36};
```

The changing order of the numbers in `some_set` depends on the operations that you do to `some_set`. The contents of `some_set` immediately after creation is not defined, but it probably won't be `{1,3,5,7,9,12,14,16,18,19,21,23,25,27,30,32,34,36}`. You can see this with a simple demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

int main() {
    typedef const std::unordered_set<short> set_t;
    set_t some_set = {1,3,5,7,9,12,14,16,18,19,21,23,25,27,30,32,34,36};

    for (short s : some_set)
        std::cout << s << std::endl;

    // The order won't change if we don't modify the contents
    std::cout << "AGAIN!" << std::endl;
    for (short s : some_set)
        std::cout << s << std::endl;

    // If we put a bunch of stuff in
    for (short s = 31; s < 100; s += 4)
        some_set.insert(s);

    // The elements from *before* the modification are not necessarily in the
    // same order as before.
    std::cout << "MODIFIED" << std::endl;
    for (short s : some_set)
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```